# Google Analytics - Regular Expression Goal URL Not Matching Page Views

Tags: regex, url, google-analytics

For some reason - my goal URL page loads don't match my overall goals tracked in Google Analytics.

When a form is completed on my site - the URL will be appended with the following:

```
?enquiry_sent
```

so `www.mysite.com` would become `www.mysite.com/?enquiry_sent`

I am using the following regular expression to try and track the URL loads:

```
.*\?enquiry_sent.*|.*\?enquiry_sent
```

Yesterday - we started testing across the site and out of over 75 forms submitted we only registered 7 goals in GA.

The unique page loads for the urls with ?enquiry_sent are all in Google Analytics but just not being registered as a goal.

Does anyone know why this is happening or how we may fix this?

Comment: perhaps when a url already contains a question mark denoting the start of a url query, the enquiry_sent query parameter is appended as &enquiry_sent instead of ?enquiry_sent. If so, you could try this: [?&]enquiry_sent(?:[&#]|$)

Comment: From what I can see on the content -> pages report in GA none of the URLs have a ? before the one in the enquiry sent.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex doesn't make sense. It should be just:

```
.*\?enquiry_sent.*
```

Comment: Bohemian - Yeah I picked this one up and have adjusted to that. It still should have been picked up with the initial regex. The update has not solved the issue.

Comment: Your initial regex would need `?enquiry_sent` to appear *twice* (because you didn't use brackets). I think you meant `(.*\?enquiry_sent.*)|(.*\?enquiry_sent)` but that's just repeating the same regex twice, like `A or A` logic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just updating this thread as I have had a response from the team at Google. Apparently there was no issues with the regex that was used.

Google has let me know that Goal Completions are actually a measure of how many **visits** result in a goal completion, rather than how many times a goal is actually completed.

So while in my situation there were over 75 leads submitted from the website - they were only submitted from 7 visits, hence only 7 of the conversions were counted in the goal completions report.